# Selenium Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network

Tags: python, selenium

I got this problems, when i need to go from google to the site more than 10k times, this problem is appears after 35+ times, it's so boring to wait for it, and then doing some stuffs to rechange my IP.
I using Chrome for this and google.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\chromedriver')
```

I had idea to auth to my account, but i failt it.

```
def check_click_xpath(_xpath_):
try:
    time.sleep(1)
    element_click_xpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath(_xpath_)
    time.sleep(2)
    element_click_xpath.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    School_list_result.append(" ")
    
def get_url(url, _xpath, send_keys):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
            time.sleep(1) 
            _element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(_xpath)
            driver.implicitly_wait(3)
            _element.send_keys(schools, send_keys)
            _element.send_keys(u'\ue007')
            driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    except NoSuchElementException:
            School_list_result.append(" ")
            
def check_xpath(xpath):
        try:
            element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
            School_list_result.append(element.text)
            time.sleep(1)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            School_list_result.append(" ")
            time.sleep(1)

for schools, links in zip(List[495:1000], List_links[494:1000]):
        get_url("https://www.google.com/", '//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input'," " + links)
        check_click_xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a/h3')
    
        time.sleep(2)
    
        check_xpath('//*[@id="outer-container"]/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[11]/td/div') #all
```

I used this code. I tried to do it in FireFox, but firefox have the same problem. There are a way to avoid this problem?

Comment: I have also got the similar issue while automating the Lazada Website https://member.lazada.com.my/user/login?spm=a2o4k.home.header.d5.5abc2e7esej1ET&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lazada.com.my%2F%23